# How Do I Print only the lines that contain the third column(Linux)

Tags: linux, grep

I have the below lines in a text file, but want to select/print only those ones with the third column:

```
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER|234908743|
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER|234909544|
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER|234809956|5008596|   
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER|234809201|
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER|234908513|
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER|234818667|2000010|
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER|234817353|
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER|234817553|
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER|234818966|5008611|   
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER|234817611|2000010|   
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER|234817511|
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER|234909292|
```

The output to be like this:

```
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER|234809956|5008596|   
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER|234818667|2000010|
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER|234818966|5008611|   
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER|234817611|2000010|
```

I have tried this command but did not produce desired result:

```
cat DEF01_resultBB.txt | grep "SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER"|$3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with e.g. awk:

```
awk -F '|' '/SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER/ && $3' DEF01_resultBB.txt
```

Or grep:

```
grep 'SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER|.*|.*|' DEF01_resultBB.txt
```

From what you've shown of the input, filtering for `SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER` is redundant because it appears in all lines, so you could shorten the above to

```
awk -F '|' '$3' DEF01_resultBB.txt
```

and

```
grep '|.*|.*|' DEF01_resultBB.txt
```

respectively.

Or you could count `|` characters and only output lines that have 3 of them:

```
perl -ne 'print if tr/|// == 3' DEF01_resultBB.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$ grep -E '^([^\|]+\|){3} *$' DEF01_resultBB.txt
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER|234809956|5008596|
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER|234818667|2000010|
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER|234818966|5008611|
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER|234817611|2000010|
```

Regex is very powerful, you can try it out here: https://regex101.com/r/NZB5GZ/1

Note that some of your lines have extra whitespace at the end, hence the `<space>*` at the end of the expression.

---

`grep -E` means to interpret the pattern as an extended regular expression which is what we have here. If you have [GNU grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/grep-Programs.html#index-_002d_002dextended_002dregexp), you can also use `--extended-regexp` instead.

A build up of the regex as requested:

- `[^\|]` matches any character *apart from* what is listed inside the square brackets, so excluding `|`

  - `[...]` matches any character inside
  - `[^...]` matches any character that *is not* inside
  - `|` has special meaning in some situations in regex, so it's safer to always escape it if you mean a literal `|` - technically in this situation (in square brackets) the escape is unnecessary
- `[^\|]+` matches the above *one-or-more* times
- `[^\|]+\|` matches any string that does not contain a pipe, but ends with a pipe
- `([^\|]+\|)` produces a match group of the above - important for the next step
- `([^\|]+\|){3}` matches the above *exactly-three* times
- `([^\|]+\|){3} *` matches the above followed by *zero-or-more* spaces

  - important as some of your lines have extra spaces on the end
- `^([^\|]+\|){3} *$` uses the `^` and `$` anchors with tie the expression to the beginning and end of the line respectively

Comment: A little explanation wouldn't hurt. Like what does `-E` stand for, what is the meaning of `{3}`, etc. I'm particularly curios about `[^\|]`. Why isn't `[^|]` enough? GNU grep 3.1 works fine without the backslash.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu updated, including my rationale for escaping the pipe - consistency.

Answer (score 2):

Set the field separator to `|` and output only the rows containing four columns (fourth column is empty).

```
awk -F '|' 'NF==4' file
```

Output:

```
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER|234809956|5008596|   
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER|234818667|2000010|
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER|234818966|5008611|   
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER|234817611|2000010|
```